# Sampling vector so they will have a given euclidean distances matrix

Tags: sampling, matrix, distance, euclidean

Given a matrix $M\in\mathbb{R}^{P\times P}$ , is it possible to sample $P$ vectors $u_i\in\mathbb{R}^N$, $i=1..P$ so that $\|u_i-u_j\|=M_{ij}$.

Obviously for not any $M$ this is possible, i.e. it has to be symmetric, have zero diagonal, etc., but assume $M$ was created from a different set of vectors which satisfied this property.

By "sampling" above I mean that I would like to have a generative procedure with this property, and allow it to build on any existing sampling process, e.g. sampling matrices using Gaussian or Uniform distribution for each entry.

Comment: The probability that $\|U_i-U_j\|=M_{ij}$ is zero for a continuous random vector.

Comment: @Xi'an, I imagine a procedure which sample some matrix $X$ using some simple scheme (e.g. Gaussian or Uniform), then use some deterministic processing which depend on M and will result in $u_i$ with the requested property.

Comment: Question answered [at the sister site](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/21404/sampling-vector-so-they-will-have-a-given-euclidean-distances-matrix/21407#21407).